# there is no passwordencoder mapped for the id null / how to map an id?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

This is my first time using spring, spring security, or doing anything with jwts, so please be patient with me.

If I send a POST request to api/user/login using insomnia with the body

```
{"email": "validmail.com",
"password": "123"}
```

I get the error 500, Internal Server error, and the exception

```
ERROR 12736 --- [nio-8088-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
```

I looked online and i understood it that adding for example {noop} to the front of the password would provide the id with which the password is to be encoded.

But changing the input to

```
{"email": "validmail.com",
"password": "{noop}123"}
```

did not change the results.

Now my question is: How do I provide an id for the DelegatingPasswordEncoder to delegate to?

Note that i haven't hashed the passwords entered into my database yet.

Relevant code:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9099175240545719086L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String writtenSignaturePath;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String passwordHash;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column
    private String twoFACode;

    protected User() {

    }

    public User(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        if (twoFACode != null){
            String[] roles;
            if (isAdmin){
                roles = new String[]{"user", "admin"};
            } else {
                roles = new String[]{"user"};
            }
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(roles);
        }
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getWrittenSignaturePath() {
        return writtenSignaturePath;
    }

    public void setWrittenSignaturePath(final String writtenSignaturePath) {
        this.writtenSignaturePath = writtenSignaturePath;
    }


    // This is called getUsername to satisfy the interface. Users are identified by their email, so this should work fine
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    // This is called getPassword to satisfy the interface.
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(final String passwordHash) {
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(final boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }

    public String getTwoFACode() {
        return twoFACode;
    }

    public void setTwoFACode(final String twoFACode) {
        this.twoFACode = twoFACode;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() { //<6>
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

}
```

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }



    //This is called loadUserByUsername to satisfy the interface. Users are usually identified by their email.
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByEmail(final String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties("security")
public final class SecurityConstants {

    private String authLoginUrl;

    private String jwtSecret;
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final SecurityConstants securityConstants;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final SecurityConstants securityConstants) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.securityConstants = securityConstants;

        setFilterProcessesUrl(this.securityConstants.getAuthLoginUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        List<String> roles = user.getAuthorities()
            .stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        byte[] signingKey = securityConstants.getJwtSecret().getBytes();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setHeaderParam("typ", securityConstants.getTokenType())
            .setIssuer(securityConstants.getTokenIssuer())
            .setAudience(securityConstants.getTokenAudience())
            .setSubject(user.getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000)) // + 1 Tag
            .claim("rol", roles)
            .compact();

        response.addHeader(securityConstants.getTokenHeader(), securityConstants.getTokenPrefix() + token);
    }
}

    // JWT Token-Standardvalues
    private String tokenHeader;
    private String tokenPrefix;
    private String tokenType;
    private String tokenIssuer;
    private String tokenAudience;

    public String getAuthLoginUrl() {
        return authLoginUrl;
    }

    public void setAuthLoginUrl(String authLoginUrl) {
        this.authLoginUrl = authLoginUrl;
    }

    public String getJwtSecret() {
        return jwtSecret;
    }

    public void setJwtSecret(String jwtSecret) {
        this.jwtSecret = jwtSecret;
    }

    public String getTokenHeader() {
        return tokenHeader;
    }

    public void setTokenHeader(String tokenHeader) {
        this.tokenHeader = tokenHeader;
    }

    public String getTokenPrefix() {
        return tokenPrefix;
    }

    public void setTokenPrefix(String tokenPrefix) {
        this.tokenPrefix = tokenPrefix;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getTokenIssuer() {
        return tokenIssuer;
    }

    public void setTokenIssuer(String tokenIssuer) {
        this.tokenIssuer = tokenIssuer;
    }

    public String getTokenAudience() {
        return tokenAudience;
    }

    public void setTokenAudience(String tokenAudience) {
        this.tokenAudience = tokenAudience;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig
    extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthorizationFilter.class);
    private final  SecurityConstants securityConstants;

    public JwtAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final SecurityConstants securityConstants) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.securityConstants = securityConstants;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
        if (authentication == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(securityConstants.getTokenHeader());
        if (token != null && !token.equals("") && token.startsWith(securityConstants.getTokenPrefix())) {
            try {
                byte[] signingKey = securityConstants.getJwtSecret().getBytes();

                Jws<Claims> parsedToken = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(signingKey).build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(securityConstants.getTokenPrefix(), "").strip());

                String username = parsedToken.getBody().getSubject();

                List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = ((List<?>) parsedToken.getBody()
                    .get("rol")).stream()
                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority((String) authority))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

                if (username != null && !username.equals("")) {
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                }
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException exception) {
                LOG.warn("Request to parse expired JWT : {} failed : {}", token, exception.getMessage());
            } catch (UnsupportedJwtException exception) {
                LOG.warn("Request to parse unsupported JWT : {} failed : {}", token, exception.getMessage());
            } catch (MalformedJwtException exception) {
                LOG.warn("Request to parse invalid JWT : {} failed : {}", token, exception.getMessage());
            } catch (SignatureException exception) {
                LOG.warn("Request to parse JWT with invalid signature : {} failed : {}", token, exception.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
                LOG.warn("Request to parse empty or null JWT : {} failed : {}", token, exception.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final SecurityConstants securityConstants;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final SecurityConstants securityConstants) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.securityConstants = securityConstants;

        setFilterProcessesUrl(this.securityConstants.getAuthLoginUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //Why doesn't this get closed? Idk, have to take care of this later
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String body = builder.toString();
        String[] params = body.split(",");
        String email = params[0].substring(12, params[0].length()-1);
        String password = params[1].substring(14, params[1].length()-2);
        System.out.println(email);
        System.out.println(password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        List<String> roles = user.getAuthorities()
            .stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        byte[] signingKey = securityConstants.getJwtSecret().getBytes();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setHeaderParam("typ", securityConstants.getTokenType())
            .setIssuer(securityConstants.getTokenIssuer())
            .setAudience(securityConstants.getTokenAudience())
            .setSubject(user.getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000)) // + 1 Tag
            .claim("rol", roles)
            .compact();

        response.addHeader(securityConstants.getTokenHeader(), securityConstants.getTokenPrefix() + token);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityConstants.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final SecurityConstants securityConstants;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(SecurityConstants securityConstants) {
        this.securityConstants = securityConstants;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityConstants))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityConstants))
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security requires a `PasswordEncoder` when working with user passwords, you have not provided information about it. You need declare bean with it, for example using [`BCryptPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html):

```java
@Bean
PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

and use it in your code. You can find many examples on the internet, like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt).

If, for any reason, we don't want to encode the configured password, we can make use of the [`NoOpPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.html).

Comment: I forgot to add the SecurityConfig in my post, sorry about that, i edited it. does the ``` @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }``` Not fulfill that purpose?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't use before `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()`, but in [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-password-storage), in 3rd paragraph, the configuration is a bit more elaborate. Maybe try with this? Secondly, you're sure the password is hashed for the user?

Comment: No, the password isn't hashed yet, I should have mentioned that, but the noop encoder should have worked then, right?

Comment: Well, i implemented BCryptPasswordEncoder and it doesn't throw me any more errors. Thank you, don't know why the way the tutorial gave me wouldn't work.